# CXF Configure Thread Count. Java Config

Tags: cxf, spring-java-config

Formerly, I've been using the following configuration for CXF HTTP Bus.

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="${http.endpoint.port}">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="${http.endpoint.minThreads}" maxThreads="${http.endpoint.maxThreads}" />
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

However, our team moves to Java Configuration and now we are using `org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus` for configuring Bus.
But I don't see a way to configure minThreads and maxThreads through Java Config.

Thanks in advance